# good practice to upload file to s3 using nodejs scalability and perfomance should be considered

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, multer

i have using multer to upload file in s3 and i have tried three methods to upload a file to s3

1. **memoryStorage**(default)
2. ***custom S3stroage engine**(by directly straming the file from request and uploading to s3)
3. **Diskstroage**(default)

in my case the **second** approach is good in perfomance wise but i think its not scalable that much.but second method saves lots of time(instead of writing to disk and then streaming from there its much more stright forward).but i dont know what will the cons of this approach.can any one suggest me a good approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should consider using [S3 Pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)

So instead of using your instance as middleman for the transaction, create an API which allow the client to retrieve **a short-lived unique (s3 direct) url**, which the client can use to upload the file directly to your desired location in S3 without going through your instance. I believe this is more scalable than your existing solutions.

However, there's a caveat. Your pre-signed url (as the name suggested) is "pre-authenticated", be careful on serving this information to your client, and ensure the url is shortlived enough to prevent further abuse.

Also, you might need additional implementation of listening to S3 event if you want to get notified when files are uploaded successfully to the storage. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html

Comment: S3 Pre-signed URL is not safe for upload. so you send me a S3 Pre-signed URL to read file since you gave me write permission too for upload I can always change file and delete it . Its like whoever has url can do all according to permission. Best way to upload a file to s3 is with sdk and keep security model intact. Bypassing security doesnot make it fast .It just makes it more vulnerable.

Comment: I pretty sure i mentioned the caveats in my answer :)

Comment: I have never seen any body using S3 Pre-signed URL to upload file ever. you need your cert  and environment variable like this [default] ; default profile
aws_access_key_id = <DEFAULT_ACCESS_KEY_ID>
aws_secret_access_key = <DEFAULT_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>
    
[personal-account] ; personal account profile
aws_access_key_id = <PERSONAL_ACCESS_KEY_ID>
aws_secret_access_key = <PERSONAL_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>
    
[work-account] ; work account profile
aws_access_key_id = <WORK_ACCESS_KEY_ID>
aws_secret_access_key = <WORK_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>

Answer (score 4):

The aws-cli is excellent but if you're worried about scaling you can use background workers to upload your files to s3. first, save the file to DiskStorage and add a job to the queue for the background process that uploads the file to aws-s3.
this method gives you an option to retry the upload if it fails and deletes it once it has been uploaded leaving you more free space. you can try [bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull)(queue system).

Answer (score -1):

use aws sdk. Its fast and secure.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html

you don't need presigned url to upload any file.I don't know why it answers any question.

Always read from disk storage Diskstroage(default). In case file is not read fully you can retry it. 
[check these github samples](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javascript/example_code/s3)

```
    // Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

// Create S3 service object
s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});

// call S3 to retrieve upload file to specified bucket
var uploadParams = {Bucket: process.argv[2], Key: '', Body: ''};
var file = process.argv[3];

// Configure the file stream and obtain the upload parameters
var fs = require('fs');
var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
fileStream.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('File Error', err);
});
uploadParams.Body = fileStream;
var path = require('path');
uploadParams.Key = path.basename(file);

// call S3 to retrieve upload file to specified bucket
s3.upload (uploadParams, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } if (data) {
    console.log("Upload Success", data.Location);
  }
});
To run the example, type the following at the command line.

node s3_upload.js BUCKET_NAME FILE_NAME
```

Comment: The OP is asking for a *scalable* solution. The "how to upload using sdk" is not actually the question.

Comment: @yman  Always read from disk storage Diskstroage(default). In case file is not read fully you can retry it. I already picked the right way to upload file out of three options he gave.